# How does this JavaScript sort function work?

Tags: javascript

I found this on a book. It is not well explained there, specially 'vals.sort(compare)' part. Can anyone please explain me this?

```
<script>

function compare ( value1, value2) {
    if (value1 > value2) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (value2 > value1) {
        return -1
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

var vals = [12,93,41,62,99]
vals.sort(compare)
document.write(vals)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is an array utility function used to sort array values according to conditionals.
2. If `sort()` is called without passing an anonymous function or named function, the values are sorted according to each character's `Unicode` code point value by default.
3. In javascript, you can pass functions either anonymously(`function(){...}`) or by name like:

   `function myFunction(){}`

   `[].sort(myFunction);`
4. Note, you only pass the function **name** and not like `myFunction()` becuase this will execute the function and pass in what is returned(which is not what we want)
5. In the callback function passed into `sort()`, for example, `compare(a,b)`, returning

   `-1` -> a is **less than** b

   `0`  -> a is **equal** to b

   `1`  -> a is **greatar** than b

Comment: @Alex, thank you! Ive been wrestling with it to get the `code` to work! :)

Comment: Thanks for the easy explanation.

Comment: @SajibDevnathAkash, welcome. Please let me know if you want me to explain something in further detail

Comment: .That's so nice of you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can pass the compare function as as argument for the sort method or write it inline, e.g.

```
<script>
   var a = [30,2,1,9,15];
   a.sort(function(a,b) { return a-b; });
   document.write(a);
</script>
```

or we can specify the compare method and call it explicitly as in your case.

When the sort() method is called, it compares two values. It sends the values to the compare function, and sorts the values according to the returned (negative, zero, positive) value.